# LuaLaTeX/beamer: print math equations as properly as PDFLaTeX

Tags: beamer, luatex, math-fonts

The following MWE has been compiled by both pdflatex and lualatex. For pdflatex, it is very fine, but for lualatex, the equations are not printed as properly as pdflatex.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,bm}
\newcommand\vm[1]{\bm{\mathrm{#1}}}
\newcommand\pbm[1]{\left(\mathbf{#1}\right)}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{align}
    \vm{\Phi}_{,\gamma}^T & = \vm{P}_{,\gamma}^T\pbm{x}\,\vm{A}^{-1}\,\vm{B} = \left\{ \begin{array}{c c c c}
    \phi_1 & \phi_2 & \cdots & \phi_n 
    \end{array} \right\}_{\left(1 \times n\right)},\\
    %
    \mathbf{\tilde{T}_s} & =%
    \left\{%
    \begin{array}{ccccc}
    T_1 & T_2 & \cdots & T_n & \bm{0}_{\left( 1 \times m \right)} 
    \end{array}%
    \right\}^T
\end{align}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### using pdflatex

[image]

### using lualatex

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The roman font used for math apparently doesn't have Greek in the control character slots as used in the classic tex math encoding. Just using bm rather that (the rather odd looking) `\bm{\mathrm{#1}}` seems to work:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[professionalfonts]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,bm}
\newcommand\vm[1]{\bm{#1}}
\newcommand\pbm[1]{\left(\mathbf{#1}\right)}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{align}
    \vm{\Phi}_{,\gamma}^T & = \vm{P}_{,\gamma}^T\pbm{x}\,\vm{A}^{-1}\,\vm{B} = \left\{ \begin{array}{c c c c}
    \phi_1 & \phi_2 & \cdots & \phi_n 
    \end{array} \right\}_{\left(1 \times n\right)},\\
    %
    \mathbf{\tilde{T}_s} & =%
    \left\{%
    \begin{array}{ccccc}
    T_1 & T_2 & \cdots & T_n & \bm{0}_{\left( 1 \times m \right)} 
    \end{array}%
    \right\}^T
\end{align}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I highly appreciate your swift consideration. I just have two more inquries: 1- is it safe to use `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{mathserif}`? 2- how to properly typeset `\tilde{T}`?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou I have no idea what `\usefonttheme{onlymath]{serif}` does so can't answer to whetehr it's safe. `\tilde{T}` is the correct markup but apparently something has messed up the math fonts. I thought `professionalfonts` was supposed to tell beamer not to mess so much with the math but I know very little about beamer. In any case it seems to be a different question.

Comment: `\widetilde{T}` seems to work better then `\tilde{T}`, but still not bold. `\usefonttheme{onlymath]{serif}` is documented in the `beamer` documentation (on page 192; it makes the math use the serif font), so I guess it's safe.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a math font issue (The `metropolis` theme uses Fira Sans Light for LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX). The following works in XeLaTeX; note the that order of loading some packages are important:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}  %% needs to be loaded before mathspec. already includes amsmath
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[BoldFont=Fira Sans Bold]{Fira Sans Light}
\newcommand\hmmax{0} %% These two lines needed
\newcommand\bmmax{0} %% to avoid "Too many  symbol fonts" error
\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand\vm[1]{\bm{\mathrm{#1}}}
\newcommand\pbm[1]{\left(\mathbf{#1}\right)}
```

As for `\tilde{T}`: using `\widehat{T}` seems to work better, but I can't get the tilde itself to be bold.

Comment: Thanks for consideration. However, I got multiple errors of need for `Xelatex` and undefined control sequence {\relax} and symbols. You might take a look at the [log file](http://pastebin.com/cxrW1CPh)

Comment: The `mathspec` package requires XeLaTeX. Could you post an addendum with a LuaLaTeX-based solution?

Comment: @Mico I added a note that this works only for XeLaTeX; since there's now an accepted answer I'll stop my experimenting with `unicode-math` (I'm having problems getting the bold math to cooperate).